# Django MySQL Database location and setup

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-mysql

So I have a MySQL database for my Django project which I think is located in the default directly (wherever that should be). When I want to move my Django project to digital ocean, how do I move that database? The my.cnf file is located inside the same directory as the settings.py file for the Django project. I am using macOS.

In short: How do I copy my database file to my Django project directory and reconfigure its path to that?

Comment: You should dump and reimport the data.

Comment: @KlausD. How do I do that? Could you maybe provide some link?

Comment: This is actually a system administration and not a programming task. It is off-topic for Stack Overflow. But any search engine is able to find leads on how to dump a database.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the MySQL versions of both servers. Ensure the new version isn't less than the current version. Also check its not two major versions ahead of the current one.

Ensure MySQL is stopped.

Copy/move the entire `datadir` to the new location. There should be no files in this new location that weren't in the original.

In the `my.cnf` file set [datadir](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_datadir) to the new location.

Copy the my.cnf file to the location where mysql is expecting to read this on the new server. Look at top of `mysqld --help --verbose` if you have doubts where this is.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to consider here,

- In Digital Ocean you would have MySQL server running on same machine as the Django server i.e just like your local machine?
- If yes then you might not have to change anything on django settings (if you keep user and password same as local).
- If No, you might need to change `host` in django to IP of that server(there are many things involved here...)
- Regarding the data transfer, it is always the best practice to dump MySQL and Import it in new DB. There are many guides available on web. [Here is one from Digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers).